# Eclipse error after installing e(fx)clipse

Tags: java, eclipse, startup, efxclipse

After I installed e(fx)clipse on my Eclipse 2018-09, I only get an error at the startup:

> An error has occurred. See the log file."

You can see the log file at: `pastebin.com/zXffdy2v`

I don't know what went wrong, it seemed it installed correctly. I'm using this installer for Java JDK: jdk-11.0.1_windows-x64_bin.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using Java 11 which does not provide `javax.xml.bind` anymore.

Some of the plug-ins you need haven't been fixed to deal with this.

Using Java 10 should be OK.

Comment: I could not find an official Download for Java 10, so I installed Java 8u191. Now it works fine! Thank you very much for the tip :)